# What is ground speed when falling vertically?

Tags: kinematics, terminology, velocity, projectile, free-fall

Ground speed as apposed to air speed. Assume a vacuum around the earth for simplicity. Just wondering if it's 0 or the absolute velocity versus the point of impact on the ground?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ground speed usually refers to the horizontal speed of an aircraft relative to the ground rather than its speed relative to the wind it is flying through. If you want to consider horizontal ground speed relative to a vertically falling object with no horizontal component, then it would be 0. If you want to consider it as the closing speed between the falling object and the ground in atmosphere, it will accelerate until the object reaches terminal velocity where air resistance equals gravitational pull. An object falling near Earth's surface with no air resistance would keep accelerating downward at g, about 9.8 meters per second squared.